# Find similar news on SQL based on similar tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of news from a few newspapers(Getting them from a RSS feed). Let's say every newspaper returns a list of news with tags. For example:

newspaper1:

- title1, tag1, tag2, tag3
- title2, tag1, tag7, tag5, tag8

newspaper2:

- title3, tag3, tag4, tag5
- title4, tag1, tag5, tag7, tag9, tag10

So, I am thinking on storing all the news in one table(newspaper_id, news_id, title), and then another table with a row per tag(news_id, tag_name).

Now, I need to query the tables and compare every news from the first newspaper with the rest of newspaper news and returns similar news. In my sample data, title1 shares one tag with title3 and 4 from the other newspaper. And title2, shares 3 tags with title4, and just one tag with title3. I need this, **how many tags every news from a newspaper share with the rest**

I have been trying hard with GROUP BY or INNER JOIN on the same table with no luck. Any idea?

Create table and insert data statements:

```
CREATE TABLE news (
newspaper_id INT(6),
news_id INT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL 
); 

CREATE TABLE tags ( 
news_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
); 


INSERT INTO `news`VALUES (1, 1, 'USA elections'), (1, 2, 'Coronavirus crisis'), (2, 3, 'Another thing about USA elections'), (2, 4, 'Who will win elections?'), (3, 5, 'Coronavirus affetcs elections');
INSERT INTO `tags`VALUES (1, 'elections'), (1, 'biden'), (1, 'trump'), (2, 'coronavirus'), (3, 'biden'), (3, 'trump'), (3, 'elections'), 
(4, 'elections'), (5, 'coronavirus'), (5, 'elections');
```

Expected results:

```
| Title                  | news_id || compared_news_id || Tags in common |
| ---------------------- | ------- || ---------------- || -------------- |
| 'USA elections'        | 1       || 3                || 3              |
| 'USA elections'        | 1       || 4                || 1              |
| 'USA elections'        | 1       || 5                || 1              |
| 'Coronavirus crisis'   | 2       || 5                || 1
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and share the `CREATE` statements of the tables. Share the sample data as `INSERT` statements into the tables. Provide the expected result with that sample data as a table or tabular text.

Comment: How does your tag table map to a title/article? It only has a newspaper_id.

Comment: EdmCoff is right; you forgot to put the title in the tag table.

Comment: You may want to take non-matching tags into consideration as well. If two titles have only one tag each and this tag matches, this sounds like a better match to me than two titles with four tags each, but only two matches.

Comment: You should tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using in order to get an appropriate answer, because SQL features may differ a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about news that don't match at all, then just look out for matching tags.

```
select
  n1.news_id, n1.title,
  n2.news_id as compared_news_id, n2.title as compared_news_title,
  count(*) as tags_in_common
from news n1
join news n2 on n2.news_id <> n1.news_id
join tags t1 on t1.news_id = n1.news_id
join tags t2 on t2.news_id = n2.news_id and t2.name = t1.name
where n1.newspaper_id = 1
group by n1.news_id, n2.news_id
order by n1.news_id, n2.news_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ff1db3be344c40b82f892654ca08e3a

If you don't want to restrict this to one newspaper, then remove `where n1.newspaper_id = 1`. In that case, if you want to avoid to have both news1/news5 and news5/news1 in your results, then change `n2.news_id <> n1.news_id` to `n2.news_id > n1.news_id`.

You can also change `on n2.news_id <> n1.news_id` to `on n2.news_id <> n1.news_id and n2.newspaper_id <> n1.newspaper_id` of course, if you don't want to compare news of the same newspaper.

Comment: I have tried something similar related to your query but still no luck. Query:
`select 
    n.newspaper_id, n.title,
    t1.name as tag_name,
    count(*) as tags_in_common
from tags t1
join tags t2
on (t2.news_id <> t1.news_id and t2.name = t1.name)
join news n on t1.news_id = n.news_id
where n.newspaper_id = 1
group by t1.news_id, t1.name, t2.news_id, t2.name`

Comment: My query selects a row per pair of two news and counts the tags they have in common. Your query selects a row per pair of two news and one tag they have in common. Then you count the tags in common, which is the one tag itself of course. You don't want a result row per tag, so don't group by tag and don't select a tag. Thank you for posting the create table statements, sample data and the desired result, I've adjusted my answer to match these.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! After reproducing the query adding one where/group step by step it is easier to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Join News and Tag tables on keys.

Step 2 : Make 2 instances of such joins.

Step 3 : Join both these instances on tags.

Step 4 : Filter out records, so that same news ids are not matched against each other in the final result.

```
select
  n1.title,
  n2.title as compared_news_title,
  n1.news_id, 
  n2.news_id as compared_news_id, 
  count(*) as tags_in_common
from 
  news n1,
  tags t1, 
  news n2, 
  tags t2 
where 
t1.news_id = n1.news_id
and t2.news_id = n2.news_id
and t2.name = t1.name
and n2.news_id <> n1.news_id
group by n1.news_id, n2.news_id
order by n1.news_id, n2.news_id;
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/870f163/5/0)

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, same query than previous answer. I accepted the other one because I will filter it out using a newspaper_id